# JavaFx Bindings and Localization

Tags: java, localization, javafx

I am localizing my relatively simple JavaFx app. "manually" (i.e. I don't use the SceneBuilder or anything). Now I'd like to add support for dynamic localization, so that the user does not have to restart the application for changes to apply.

The only part in my app that needs to be localized in this manner, are the tooltips. (I'm using lots of ControlsFX dialogs, and they are re-created every time so there is no problem there...)

I have not used the JavaFx binding system before, but I have a hunch that it could make this task very simple.

Currently, I am just setting the tooltips like so:

```
myButton.setTooltip(new Tooltip(Utils.i8n("mybutton")));
```

I've read something about the JavaFx bindings, but I'm a bit overwhelmed by the amount of choices I seem to have! How would I go on (ab)using the binding system to help me localize these tooltips "dynamically"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class Utils {
    private static final ObjectProperty<Locale> locale = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(Locale.getDefault());
    public static ObjectProperty<Locale> localeProperty() {
        return locale ;
    }
    public static Locale getLocale() {
        return locale.get();
    }
    public static void setLocale(Locale locale) {
        localeProperty().set(locale);
    }

    public static String i18n(String key) {
        return ResourceBundle.getBundle("bundleName", getLocale()).getString(key);
    }
}
```

then

```
myButton.setTooltip(createBoundTooltip("mybutton"));
```

with

```
private Tooltip createBoundTooltip(final String key) {
    Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip();
    tooltip.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding( 
         () -> Utils.i18n(key), Utils.localeProperty()));
    return tooltip ;
}
```

Then `Utils.setLocale(...)` should automatically update the tooltip text. You can also do fun stuff like

```
ComboBox<Locale> languages = new ComboBox<>();
languages.getItems().addAll(new Locale("en"), new Locale("fr"), new Locale("fi"), new Locale("ru"));
languages.setConverter(new StringConverter<Locale>() {
    @Override
    public String toString(Locale l) {
        return l.getDisplayLanguage(l);
    }
    @Override
    public Locale fromString(String s) {
        // only really needed if combo box is editable
        return Locale.forLanguageTag(s);
    }
});

Utils.localeProperty().bind(languages.valueProperty());
```

Comment: And it works like a charm, this is exactly what I was after! Thank you.